Quantum Computing: Quantum teleportation circuit
Given the following quantum teleportation circuit. It is required to calculate $\psi_i$ for $i=\{1,...,6\}$.
My answer for
$\psi_3 = [\alpha/2,\beta/2,\beta/2,\alpha/2,\alpha/2,-\beta/2,-\beta/2,\alpha/2]$
and (post-measurement state)
$\psi_4 = [\alpha/\sqrt{\alpha^2+\beta^2},\beta/\sqrt{\alpha^2+\beta^2},0,0,0,0,0,0].$
But the correct answer is $\psi_4=[\alpha, \beta, 0,0,0,0,0,0]$. I can not derive this answer? Anyone who knows the calculation steps?
Thanks in advance.
enter image description here

hi welcome to MSE, please write your question in the form of mathjax

I have "mathjax-ed" the beginning of your question. Please learn from that to enclose your expressions with dollar signs, to use backslashes and curly brackets...

In writing $\psi=\alpha|0\rangle+\beta|1\rangle$, they have implicitly assumed $|\alpha|^2+|\beta|^2=1$ since $\psi$ would otherwise not be a normalized state. Hence your $\psi_4$ is equivalent to the indicated answer.
